# Why does my Raspberry unable to detect fan through i2c?

Tags: pi-4, i2c

I recently bought a Argon One V2 M2 house for my Raspberry Pi to speed things up and have it cool, but the issue is i2c shows all addresses.

After some research figured it means either a circuit issue or some bad injured cable, although the fans spins up for about 3 seconds at boot, then go dead silent.

Now the thing is, when the jumper on the house is on Always On Mode, the fans spins just fine, though on max speed all the time.

```
marcell@raspberry:/$ sudo i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f
10: 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f
20: 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 2a 2b 2c 2d 2e 2f
30: 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 3a 3b 3c 3d 3e 3f
40: 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4a 4b 4c 4d 4e 4f
50: 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 5a 5b 5c 5d 5e 5f
60: 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6a 6b 6c 6d 6e 6f
70: 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77
```

I am cureless on what's going on?

Comment: Please post a wiring diagram. Perhaps you have connected the fan to the wrong pins.

Comment: A close-up photo of the connections would be better.

Comment: It has no such a wiring like this here. Argon One V2 M2 is a house that comes with a fan inbuilt.

Comment: I did some tests, which seems to confirm GPIO2 might be broken.

https://pastebin.com/raw/VxGzEFnz

Comment: In case GPIO 46 & 47 aren't externally pulled, you might have an issue with those as well.

Comment: @goldilocks When looking at pictures of the _Argon ONE M.2_ case, I don't think there is any wiring on OPs part.

Comment: @goldilocks how I am supposed to show any wirings when it's directly attached? It's a case, nothing wires. That's why I have added the name of the case in the first place. My apology if I was not clear, but obviously I would have shown a pic in case I manually wired it.

Comment: Have you checked that SDA & SCL haven't been swapped over on any of your I2C devices?

Comment: I really don't have any I2C device other than this fan which comes with the case directly attached. How can I check if the fan connector is swapped?